# initialize multiple tflite models with GPU delegate v2 api through multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, delegates, initialization, tensorflow-lite

I tried to initialize multiple tflite models with GPU delegate v2 api at the same time through multi-threading, but found that it takes about the same time for multi-threading to initialize multiple models at the same time and single-threading to initialize multiple models sequentially，Can someone explain why~

```
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/delegate.h"

static int
modify_graph_with_delegate (tflite_interpreter_t *p, tflite_createopt_t *opt)
{
    TfLiteDelegate *delegate = NULL;

#if defined (USE_GPU_DELEGATEV2)
    const TfLiteGpuDelegateOptionsV2 options = {
        .is_precision_loss_allowed = 1, // FP16
        .inference_preference = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PREFERENCE_FAST_SINGLE_ANSWER,
        .inference_priority1 = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_MIN_LATENCY,
        .inference_priority2 = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_AUTO,
        .inference_priority3 = TFLITE_GPU_INFERENCE_PRIORITY_AUTO,
    };
    delegate = TfLiteGpuDelegateV2Create(&options);
#endif

    if (!delegate)
        return 0;

    if (p->interpreter->ModifyGraphWithDelegate(delegate) != kTfLiteOk)
    {
        DBG_LOGE ("ERR: %s(%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int
tflite_create_interpreter_from_file (tflite_interpreter_t *p, const char *model_path)
{
    p->model = FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile (model_path);
    if (!p->model)
    {
        DBG_LOGE ("ERR: %s(%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    InterpreterBuilder(*(p->model), p->resolver)(&(p->interpreter));
    if (!p->interpreter)
    {
        DBG_LOGE ("ERR: %s(%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    char *env_tflite_num_threads = getenv ("FORCE_TFLITE_NUM_THREADS");
    if (env_tflite_num_threads)
    {
        num_threads = atoi (env_tflite_num_threads);
        DBG_LOGI ("@@@@@@ FORCE_TFLITE_NUM_THREADS=%d\n", num_threads);
    }
    DBG_LOG ("@@@@@@ TFLITE_NUM_THREADS=%d\n", num_threads);
    p->interpreter->SetNumThreads(num_threads);

    if (modify_graph_with_delegate (p, NULL) < 0)
    {
        DBG_LOGE ("ERR: %s(%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        //return -1;
    }

    if (p->interpreter->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk)
    {
        DBG_LOGE ("ERR: %s(%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void *
init_tflite_face_detect(void *model_buf_t)
{
    const char *model_buf = (const char *)model_buf_t;
    /* Face detect */
    int iret = tflite_create_interpreter_from_file(&s_detect_interpreter, model_buf);

    tflite_get_tensor_by_name (&s_detect_interpreter, 0,
            "normalized_input_image_tensor", &s_detect_tensor_input);  //    input
    tflite_get_tensor_by_name (&s_detect_interpreter, 1,
            "TFLite_Detection_PostProcess",  &s_detect_tensor_bboxes);  //   bboxes
    tflite_get_tensor_by_name (&s_detect_interpreter, 1,
            "TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1",  &s_detect_tensor_classes);  //  classes
    tflite_get_tensor_by_name (&s_detect_interpreter, 1,
            "TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2", &s_detect_tensor_scores); //   score of faces
    tflite_get_tensor_by_name (&s_detect_interpreter, 1,
            "TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3", &s_detect_tensor_number); //  number of faces

    return 0;

int 
init_multhread(const char *FD_Model_Path, const char *IQA_Model_Path){
    clock_t start,end;
    start = clock();
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, init_tflite_face_detect, (void *)FD_Model_Path);
    pthread_create(&pid2, NULL, init_tflite_face_iqa, (void *)IQA_Model_Path);
    pthread_join(pid, NULL);
    pthread_join(pid2, NULL);
    end=clock();
    double endtime=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("======>multithread cost time:％f" % endtime);

}

int
init_sigle_thread(const char *FD_Model_Path, const char *IQA_Model_Path){
    clock_t start,end;
    start = clock();
    init_tflite_face_detect(FD_Model_Path);
    init_tflite_face_iqa(IQA_Model_Path);
    end=clock();
    double endtime=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("======>single thread cost time:％f" % endtime);
}

int
main(){
    const char * FD_Model_Path = "fd_xxx.tflite";
    const char * IQA_Model_Path = "iqa_xxx.tflite";
    init_multhread(const char *FD_Model_Path, const char *IQA_Model_Path);
    init_sigle_thread(const char *FD_Model_Path, const char *IQA_Model_Path);
}
```

======>multithread cost time: 1.8s
======>single thread cost time: 1.9s

Comment: How big are your models? I suspect that one model is much bigger than the other.

Anyway, these init is only one-time run, is there a need to optimize it with multi-threading?

Comment: @Thaink  Unless it can be pre-initialized, it will be time-consuming to initialize multiple models when in use, so I hope that models can be initialized in multi-threading, In addition, the two models are about the same size

Comment: My guess is one thread is running on the big core, the other is on the small one. You need to force them to run on the same type of core to verify this theory though.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you mean by "core“, would you mind explaining it?

Comment: It is common in ARM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE